# Under what conditions does the control pass from Filter to Servlet in java?

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-filters

I have server running in JBOSS. there is a `Filter` which alistenes to all the requests i.e all the requests come to the Filter and are passed on to other `Servlets` from here. I have noticed this : 
 When I use the following code, only the filter is invoked but the control is not passed on to the respective Servlet(The filter prints the correct servlet when I print using `request.getRequestURI()`. It also prints correct value of the request headers `username` and `password`)

```
 HttpURLConnection connection=gs.getconnection("send_user_detail");
          connection.setRequestProperty("user", gs.get_login_id());
          connection.setRequestProperty("password", gs.get_pass());
        connection.setRequestProperty("timezone", TimeZone.getDefault().getDisplayName());
            connection.connect();
```

**BUT** when I use the following code, the control is passed on to the respective `Servlet` and works fine.

```
 HttpURLConnection connection=gs.getconnection("send_user_detail");
          connection.setRequestProperty("user", gs.get_login_id());
          connection.setRequestProperty("password", gs.get_pass());
        connection.setRequestProperty("timezone", TimeZone.getDefault().getDisplayName());
            //connection.connect();
 ObjectOutputStream out=new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
          out.writeObject("string"); //some random string not used in the servlet
```

So the control is only passed on to the servlet when I write something on the OutputStream. But with `connection.connect()`, it still goes up to the filter and even prints the correct name of the requested `Servlet`. What is the reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Writing to request body in `URLConnection` implies a HTTP POST request.

Your servlet is apparently doing the job in `doPost()`, not in `doGet()`.

You need to perform the job in `doGet()` if you want your servlet to act on HTTP GET requests.

This has completely nothing to do with filters. You'd have exactly the same problem when removing the filter.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, the `connection.setRequestProperty()` lines sets request headers, not request parameters. Make sure that you aren't abusing headers as parameters (bad design). Request parameters should in case of POST be written as URL-encoded query string in the request body.

#### See also:

- [Using java.net.URLConnection to fire and handle HTTP requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/how-to-use-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests)

Comment: No. actually it is the opposite. I am implementing doPost(). Thanks. just change the answer to the opp. I will accept it.

Comment: Right, mixed it. Fixed the answer.

Comment: Seen that post of yours a million times. That is how I came to learn all the http requests and all. Just was a little careless here:)

Comment: Please see the answer update about using `setRequestProperty()`, you seem to be actually willing to pass request parameters, not request headers.

Comment: yeah, you are right about that. But the reason I am putting it in header is that. The header is only used in the filter and I don't want to access the body in the filter.

Comment: Uh, it's just available by `request.getParameter()` like as in servlet .. ?

Comment: The body actually contains an object. I am using ObjectOutputStream to pass the object.

Comment: Ouch .. What importable. Good luck with future maintenance. I'd really consider standard and more portable formats before it's too late.

Answer (score 0):

Filters work in a chain. The filter contract is;

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException
```

Generally a filter will do some work and call

```
chain.doFilter(request, response);
```

Note that the filter can do its work before or after the filter chain call. Code before the call is invoked on the way in, before the servlet. Code after the call is invoked on the way out, after the servlet.

Note that there can be many filters in the chain, and the chain is ordered. Any filter in the chain can miss out the filter chain call which has the effect of stopping the request from propogating further up the chain and eventually reaching the servlet.

I suspect in your case that this may be what is happening.

EDIT:
Just noticed that in your second example you have commented out the call to `connection.connect();` maybe this is throwing an error in the first example?